# How can i do git for-each-ref --points-at SHA?

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

I have a SHA in hand and want to know which (if any) branches are pointing to it e.g figuring out if it's a detached head. Can i do that with libgit2sharp or any other library from C# ?

/donnib

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible at least in libgit2, and I suspect libgit2sharp should handle it.

You'll need to grab a [git_reference_iterator](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_reference_iterator), and for all of them, resolve all direct ones to their OID/SHA (symbolic ones are up to you ), check that against your detached HEAD. If it matches this ref is pointing to this OID.